# When printing pdf from Rmarkdown size of tables too big

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have tried to look into other posts but did not find anything that works

Basically when I print as pdf the html file obtained with Rmarkdown the tables end up being really huge and after trying several codes I am not really able to resize them, example below

[page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oia73.png)

also, when using `export_summs` the spacing between the lines is ridiculously wide, and I cant resize that either

[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsAD4.png)

Is there a universal way to resize tables?
something like `{r out.width="50%", out.height="50%"}` ?

Thanks,
Andriy

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible by including data to enable testing and verification of possible solutions. [Link for guidance on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide a small, reproducible example. I've tried to recreate your conditions the best I could here:

```
---
title: "PDF Table | Example"
author: "Alexander P. Christensen"
date: "2/4/2022"
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["adjustbox"]
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

## Load packages
{r load packages, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE, comment = NA, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(jtools)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

## Example Table
{r example, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE, comment = NA, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
kable(
  head(iris), booktabs = TRUE, linesep = ""
)

## Example Smaller Table (shrinks vertically)
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5} 
{r example_smaller, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE, comment = NA, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
kable(
  head(iris), booktabs = TRUE, linesep = ""
) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
```

[image: First page]

```
\newpage

## Example Even Smaller Table (shrinks vertically more)
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.25}
{r example_even_smaller, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE, comment = NA, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
kable(
  head(iris), booktabs = TRUE, linesep = ""
) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")

## Obtain LaTeX output for adjustbox (next example)
{r example_latex, echo = TRUE, eval = FALSE, comment = NA, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
kable(
  head(iris), booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "", format = "latex"
) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")

This code will output:

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{rrrrl}
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 & setosa\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

## Adjust Full Table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{adjustbox}{width = 3in, totalheight = 3in, center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrl}
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 & setosa\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

[image: Second page]

`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}` will adjust your table vertically and can be placed before any `kable()` code. I assume this works the same for `jtools::export_summs`.

`\begin{adjustbox}{width = 3in, totalheight = 3in, center}` will adjust your table to your desired dimensions automatically.

Using `adjustbox` requires a few more steps. First, you'll need to setup your YAML with extra dependencies:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["adjustbox"]
```

Second, you'll need to output a LaTeX table from `kable()` with the `format = "latex"` option:

```
kable(
  head(iris), booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "", format = "latex"
) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
```

Finally, you'll need to insert your table chunk to replace the `...` in the code below:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{adjustbox}{width = 3in, totalheight = 3in, center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrl}
\toprule

...

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Change the `width` and `totalheight` to your desired size